# How to interpret unusual results from glm model?

Tags: r, glm, logistic-regression

I am using a logistic regression model to predict values in a raster dataset.  Data used in the model are in the following format:

```
class     b1     b2     b3     b4
A         121    111    90     160
A         100    90     67     90
B         90     120    102    154
...
```

I would expect the output of the model to be categorical (A or B; there are only two classes).  Instead, the `glm` model yields continuous values ranging from 0 - 1.  Either my interpretation of the model output is incorrect, or am I coding this wrong.  How should I interpret these results?

[image]

---

```
  # GLM
  myglm = glm(factor(class) ~ b1 + b2 + b3 + b4), data = df, family = binomial(link = "logit"))

  # Predict results and write to image 
  predict(sf, myglm, outpath, type="response", 
          index=1, na.rm=TRUE, progress="text", overwrite=TRUE)
```

Comment: @rawr I don't think it's unreasonable to expect that binary outcomes might be simulated.

Comment: @jbaums the question seems to be "why are my fitted values not As and Bs" or am I wrong?

Comment: @jbaums please respond

Comment: so I can address the question and inform the two answerers (with two upvotes) who have addressed the same issue. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but you should read about logistic models. Your understanding is incorrect.

Comment: @rawr sure, that was the question. I'm just saying that I can see how the OP might expect R to stimulate binary outcomes in this scenario (and subsequently return a vector that takes values consistent with the original outcomes).

Comment: @Borealis you might consider picking an answer as we can then close the question and move on with our lives. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output is correct. You should interpret these values as probabilities. The Base class set's what the probability is for.

The value 0.7 means a 70% probability of the data point belonging to class A(or B) depending on how you set the levels.

If you want binary classes out you have to decide on a cut-off in probability. If the prevalence is 50% the 0.5 should suffice as a cut-off.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't look like you are coding it wrong. Sounds like you are predicting the probability of the target event (hence 0 to 1). Try stack exchange stats for more info on logistic regression: https://stats.stackexchange.com/

If you want a purely binary outcome, you can make an assumption on where to round up or down to force say everything below 0.55 to 0 and everything above 0.55 to 1. It will depend a lot on the rarity of the event and your own desired outcome on where you want to add the cut-off. This isn't an approach I've seen that often, but is included in some software packages like TreeNet.